# Reorder of SQLAlchemy Query results based on external ranking

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The results of an ORM query (e.g., MyObject.query()) need to be ordered according to a ranking algorithm that is based on values not within the database (i.e. from a separate search engine). This means 'order_by' will not work, since it only operates on fields within the database.

But, I don't want to convert the query results to a list, then reorder, because I want to maintain the ability to add further constraints to the query. E.g.:

```
results = MyObject.query()
results = my_reorder(results)
results = results.filter(some_constraint)
```

Is this possible to accomplish via SQLAlchemy?

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean with *application value*?

Comment: edited to reflect application value

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you will not be able to do it, unless the ordering can be derived from the fields of the object's table(s) and/or related objects' tables which *are* in the database.

But you could return from your code the tuple `(query, order_func/result)`. In this case the query can be still extended until it is executed, and then resorted. Or you could create a small `Proxy`-like class, which will contain this tuple, and will delegate the query-extension  methods to the query, and query-execution methods (`all(), __iter__`, ...) to the query and apply ordering when executed.

Also, if you could calculate the value for each `MyObject` instance beforehand, you could add a `literal` column to the query with the values and then use `order_by` to order by it. Alternatively, add temporary table, add rows with the computed ordering value, join on it in the query and add ordering. But I guess these are adding more complexity than the benefit they bring.